# typelist-like (?) template class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to achieve following: create template class which uses its template arguments to create instance of template type and use it somewhere in the, for example constructor. Consider following example:

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    explicit foo(const T& data) : m_data(data) {}
    T m_data;
};

template <typename T01, typename T02>
class bar
{
public:
    explicit bar(int data) : m_storage(T01(data), T02(data)) {}
    void print() { boost::fusion::for_each(m_storage, printer()); }

private:
    boost::fusion::vector<T01, T02> m_storage;
};
```

and usage:

```
bar<foo<int>, foo<int>> b(5);
    b.print();
```

but what if I want flexibility in the `bar` class and I want number of these T01, T02 classes varying?
example:

```
bar<foo<int>, foo<int>> b(5);
b.print();
bar<foo<int>, foo<int>>, foo<int>> c(6);
c.print();
```

Something like using argument pack maybe?

EDIT001:
Final working version on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a52a5f8e57811ce2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for variadic template (available since C++11)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class bar
{
public:
    explicit bar(int data) : m_storage(Ts(data)...) {}
    void print() { boost::fusion::for_each(m_storage, printer()); }

private:
    boost::fusion::vector<Ts...> m_storage;
};
```

Comment: just like this??? I wasn't aware that variadic pack can be instantiated like this. will check it and report back

Comment: damn! It doesnt compile with MSVC, but works fine with CLang. in any case you deserve your answer being marked as correct one. Meanwhile will open a bug on Microsoft Connect. Thanks!

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg:It should work for msvc 2013 and later.

Comment: it doesnt work for VS2015 UPD1 and does work for clang 3.7 or gcc

Comment: variadic template is supported for msvc 2013 (but msvc has still its own implementation for template). Which error do you get ?

Comment: yes, but actually I dont remember if they fully support all variadic related features, for constexpr, for example they do not. erro message: "error C2062: type 'foo<int>' unexpected" for this line " explicit bar(int data) : m_storage(Foos(data)...) {}"

Comment: no luck
error C2062: type 'foo<int>' unexpected
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
for the same line, and it crashed the compiler :)